# React native, setState is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm re-learning React native as the back isn't dev yet I'm starting fake data, so in my Modal I'm trying to put in my state future api data

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import { Modal, StyleSheet,Text,TouchableOpacity, ScrollView,View,Image } from "react-native";

const ModalInfo = (props) => {
    const {toggleVisibility,visibility} = props
    const [genre,setGenre] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {
        setGenre({
            id:"genreID",
            name:"Les Tops",
            description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at ullamcorper eros.",
            icons:[{url:"https://t.scdn.co/media/derived/toplists_11160599e6a04ac5d6f2757f5511778f_0_0_275_275.jpg"}],
        })
    },[]);

    return (
        <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={visibility}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
                <View style={styles.modalHeader}>
                    {
                        genre && genre.icons ? <Image source={{uri: `${genre.icons[0].url}`}} style={styles.images} /> : null
                    }
                    {
                        genre && genre.name ? <Text style={styles.modalText}>{genre.name}</Text> : null
                    }
                </View>
                <ScrollView style={styles.modalScroll}>
                    {
                        genre && genre.description ? <Text style={styles.modalText}>{genre.description}</Text> : null
                    }
                </ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.modalFooter}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{toggleVisibility()}} style={styles.btn}>
                        <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Rejoindre</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
};

export default ModalInfo;
```

But somehow genre is still undefined and if I don't pu ternary I've an error saying undefined.

UPDATE: when I passed something else than an Object to setGenre It work's

Comment: The genre data will be coming from an external server or they are just a constant variable ?

Comment: It will come from an external server @Tarık

Comment: *I've an error saying undefined* - what exactly is this error? Is it an eslint error? A warning from react or a true error?

Comment: Render error, Undefined is not an object (evaluating genre.icons[0].url) @BrianThompson

Comment: Also an empty object is truthy. So doing `genre &&` will always be true. Try it out in the console or somewhere by doing `!!{}` (it returns true).

Comment: If I doing this my modal is showing nothing, but no more error @BrianThompson

Comment: @BrianThompson addition to do Brian, maybe start initial state with null, then you can safely check `genre?.icons`... You do not need to do extra `genre&&`, you can use optional chaining.

Comment: Nothing change, I've no error, but my modal is empty

Comment: If you retyped this for the example (instead of copy/pasting), check all of your spelling and capitalization. useState, useEffect, genre, setGenre, and check that your imported useState and useEffect and react from react. Those are all I can figure, because I had a similar problem and it was a capitalization thing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed since I didn't really give you a suggestion to try, I just explained why your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: I ve updated the code to be sure to give every information, when I set a string inside set set genre, everything work I can show it inside my modal

Comment: `useEffect` triggers when component mounts. Which means at your first render, `genre` is indeed `null`

Comment: But inside it I update it so it must re-render to modal no ?

Comment: So did I have to put genre in my useEffect ? to make un reload ?